# I used a Preloader, but few of the images like on the main slider and in the Modal are not not being preload

Tags: jquery, html, css

I used a Preloader, but few of the images like on the main slider and in the Modal are not not being preload. They start loading after preloader finish.

I want all my content to be preloaded and then remove the preloader animation.

Here is a link:

http://muchikuchi.netau.net/index.html

here is the laoder I m using

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8"/>
   <title>PreLoadMe</title>

   <!-- Please support http://humanstxt.org/ -->
   <link type="text/plain" rel="author" href="http://www.gerbers.ch/humans.txt"/>

   <!-- Stylesheet -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen, print"/>
   
</head>

<body>
<!-- Preloader -->
<div id="preloader">
 <div id="status">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<!-- Your Website Content -->
<div>This is your website content</div>

<!-- jQuery Plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Preloader -->
<script type="text/javascript">
 //<![CDATA[
  $(window).load(function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded
   $('#status').fadeOut(0); // will first fade out the loading animation
   $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow'); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
   $('body').delay(350).css({'overflow':'visible'});
  })
 //]]>
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also Google map is starting after animation goes. I want each and everything to be preloaded. Here is an example:

https://historyoficons.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try to this solution i think it is working

```
$.preloadImages = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    $("<img />").attr("src", arguments[i]);
  }
}

$.preloadImages("img1.jpg","img2.jpg");
```

Comment: Here is the loader I m using.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS Sprites. Put all files in one (sprite) and load single file (sprite) and after hide preloader.

Image will be displayed for example

```
  background: transparent url('sprite.jpg') -50px -50px no-repeat;
```

JS:

```
  var ready=0;
  $("document").ready(ready++;if(ready>=2) {/*hide preloader*/});
  $(".sprite").on('load', function() { ready++; if(ready>=2) {/*hide preloader*/} })
```

Or load all images in hidden div and after run code. For example

```
   //first load all images      
   <div style="display:none;">
   <img src="a1">
   <img src="a2">
   </div>

   //after load js code and run and may be in this moment all images will be already loaded and after js will run and hide preloader  

   <script src="js_code_with_preloader">//scropt with preloader</script>
```